# Replacing html text on an Android WebView template with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, text, replace, webview

I'm having problems replacing some html text in an Android WebView. I have a HTML template that I load inside a WebView and after the template is fully loaded to the WebView I need to replace an < h5> header with a String but when I do this I got the whole template replaced with the String.

I'm doing this with JavaScript, any tip about this will be helpful.

Thanx in advance.
alberut.

Here is my html template inside assets folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
html, body  { 
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; }
body { 
    Color: #292F37; 
    font: 11px Helvetica, 'Lucida Grande',Arial,sans-serif; 
    text-align:left;}

p  {
    line-height: 2; 
    margin: 0 0 1.3em; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    text-align:justify;
}

/* Headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6  { margin: 1em 0; }
h1  { font-size: 22px; color:#EA772F;}
h2  { font-size: 20px; }
h3  { font-size: 18px; }
h4  { font-size: 16px; }
h5  { font-size: 14px; }
h6  { font-size: 12px; }

.headers {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #CCC;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h5 id="REPLACE_TITLE" class="headers">...header...</h5>    
    <div class="textwidget">
        <p id="REPLACE_DESCRIPTION">...description...</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my code inside a Fragment:

```
    private static final String URL2 = "file:///android_asset/product_template.html";
    private WebView myWebView2;
    myWebView2 = (WebView) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.webViewArticuloDetalle);

    myWebView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView2.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            String textToChange = "NEW TEXT";
            String javaScript = "javascript: var element = document.getElementById('REPLACE_TITLE');"
                    + "element.innerHTML = '" + textToChange + "';";
            view.loadUrl(javaScript);

        }
    });
    myWebView2.loadUrl(URL2);
```

Comment: view.loadUrl();  // here you should put your URL string or asset path

Comment: @Mohit In the last line "myWebView2.loadUrl(URL2);"  loads the URL into the WebView and after the load is complete it triggers the method onPageFinished where it is supposed to inject the JS code in the page loaded, but instead it replace the whole page with the the replaced text.

Comment: according to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) the webview object in onPageFinished()is **The WebView that is initiating the callback.** so you can try replacing your **view** to **myWebview2**

Comment: Thanx again @Mohit, tried that, but since myWebView2 and view are the same object the result still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the super method:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   super.onPageFinished(view, url);
   //...
}
```

I used your code with this call and it works.